# Converting Null to Nullable Enum (Generic)

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I'm writing some Enum functionality, and have the following:

```
public static T ConvertStringToEnumValue<T>(string valueToConvert, 
    bool isCaseSensitive)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueToConvert))
        return (T)typeof(T).TypeInitializer.Invoke(null);

    valueToConvert = valueToConvert.Replace(" ", "");
    if (typeof(T).BaseType.FullName != "System.Enum" &&
        typeof(T).BaseType.FullName != "System.ValueType")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be of Enum and not " +
            typeof (T).BaseType.FullName);
    }

    if (typeof(T).BaseType.FullName == "System.ValueType")
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)),
            valueToConvert, !isCaseSensitive);
    }

    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), valueToConvert, !isCaseSensitive);
}
```

I now call this with the following:

```
EnumHelper.ConvertStringToEnumValue<Enums.Animals?>("Cat");
```

This works as expected. However, if I run this:

```
EnumHelper.ConvertStringToEnumValue<Enums.Animals?>(null);
```

it breaks with the error that the TypeInitializer is null.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks all!

Comment: Why on earth are you invoking the type initializer?? In my 9 years of C#, I have **never** needed to do that!

Comment: In fact that type initializer does not even return anything. The code is bogus, sorry.

Comment: @leppie, hence my posting of the question. I am looking for a way to do the above, and clearly the TypeInitializer isn't the correct way of doing this. The below answer from Preet is what I was looking for.

Comment: @leppie: he's asking a question to find a better way. Isn't that what SO is all about? Why so admonishing?

Comment: May i suggest you read up on the Type API. You should avoid using string comparison on types. For instance, typeof(T).BaseType.FullName != "System.Enum" may be better written as !typeof(T).IsEnum. Also typeof(T).BaseType.FullName != "System.ValueType" may be better written as !typeof(T).IsValueType.

Comment: @Bear Monkey: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of those and will definitely use those here and in future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueToConvert))
              return default(T);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an different approach, using extension and generics.

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string s) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        return default(T);

    s = s.Replace(" ", "");
    if (typeof(T).BaseType.FullName != "System.Enum" &&
        typeof(T).BaseType.FullName != "System.ValueType") {
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be of Enum and not " + typeof(T).BaseType.FullName);
    }

    if (typeof(T).BaseType.FullName == "System.ValueType")
        return (T)Enum.Parse(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)), s, true);

    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s, true);
}
```

Use like this...

```
Gender? g = "Female".ToEnum<Gender?>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one gets the job done and it also looks pretty. Hope it helps!

```
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>More convenient than using T.TryParse(string, out T). 
    /// Works with primitive types, structs, and enums.
    /// Tries to parse the string to an instance of the type specified.
    /// If the input cannot be parsed, null will be returned.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// If the value of the caller is null, null will be returned.
    /// So if you have "string s = null;" and then you try "s.ToNullable...",
    /// null will be returned. No null exception will be thrown. 
    /// </para>
    /// <author>Contributed by Taylor Love (Pangamma)</author>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="p_self"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T? ToNullable<T>(this string p_self) where T : struct
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_self))
        {
            var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            if (converter.IsValid(p_self)) return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(p_self);
            if (typeof(T).IsEnum) { T t; if (Enum.TryParse<T>(p_self, out t)) return t;}
        }

        return null;
    }
```

https://github.com/Pangamma/PangammaUtilities-CSharp/tree/master/src/StringExtensions

Answer (score 0):

this is what I using, maybe useful for someone!

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static TEnum? ParseOrDefault<TEnum>(string value, bool ignoreCase = false, TEnum? @default = default)
        where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        TEnum? @enum;
        try { @enum = (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value, ignoreCase); }
        catch { @enum = @default; }
        return @enum;
    }
}
```